# I cannot run react native app and stacknavigation by Execution failed for task ':react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: react-native

this is the package.json

I am new to react native. Most of the time I struggled with the setUp issue. I have install all stack navigation according to the offical website but it has lots of problem.
The problem is like that:

> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 11) and 'compileDebugKotlin' task (current target is 1.8) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
> Could not perform incremental compilation: Could not connect to Kotlin compile daemon
> Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy.

> Task :react-native-svg:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
58 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 53 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

I tried on chatGPT and its method did not work.